# How to tell GC to clean embedded object as well?

Tags: c#, .net

We have an event class which has a reference of a MsgBody class:

```
public class StatusEvent
{
   MsgBody msgBody;
   public StatusEvent(MsgBody body)
   {
       msgBody = body;
   }
....
}

public class MsgBody
{
   string s1;
   string s2;
.....

}
```

`MsgBody` class is ONLY used by `StatusEvent`. No other place a `MsgBody` is refered. When a `StatusEvent` instance is created, a `MsgBody` instance will be created. When a `StatusEvent` object is ready for cleanup, a `MsgBody` object will be safe to be cleanup.

But the result is the `MsgBody` cleanup is way behind the `StatusEvent`. From one profiler result, I found there ware only 43 Live instances of `StatusEvent` but there were 9,940 instances of `MsgBody`!

Is there a way to link them together and make `GC` cleanup `MsgBody` when it wipe `StatusEvent` away?

thanks,

Comment: If what you say is true then when `StatusEvent` is collected, the `MsgBody` instance should be eligible for garbage collection. Are there any events or callback delegates used (they hold references as well)? I see it is passed in the constructor so it is created outside of the `StatusEvent` class => maybe there is a field holding the reference outside of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want deterministic release of resources, StatusEvent needs to implement IDisposable. In the IDisposable.Dispose method implementation, you can release all the resources held. In your case you can put the statement msgBody = null; to your code.

Are you sure there is no other place where msgBody is being stored?

Comment: Yes, I am sure there is no other place hold the msgBody.

Comment: It is not necessary to implement IDisposable to clear a reference.  Setting the reference to null may make the inner reference eligible for GC sooner than the owner (it might already be eligible even before it was set to null, actually), but it will also be eligible as soon as the parent object is no longer referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the GC should automatically free the memory as soon as the memory is needed anywhere else. But if you want to speed this up, you can call the following to free memory immidiately:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collect.aspx

Comment: Doing this will probably have adverse effects on the execution and is not recommended.

Comment: Sometimes it is better to call system.gc.collect manually if you know that now is enough free time to collect, but in future you will have a lot of work to do so the GC could take cpu time and memory bandwidth you need.

Comment: No, it's not better. GC.Collect is in the framework for entirely different reason namely allowing libraries to clean up large resources before the GC gets "trained". If you do this because "you know that now is enough free time" you will just disrupt the GC training and it will be less effective.

Comment: Thank you for this info! It seems that I made wrong assumptions in history. Do you have further information material regarding GC "training"?

Answer (score 0):

If the `MsgBody` does not have any expensive resource access, then the GC will take care once the object is out of scope. Aditionally you can set `msgBody=null;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call GC.Collect(), so it would totally depend on GC. I don't think there's the way to instruct GC in the manner you want.